# Take desktop screenshot WinAPI - want small size

Tags: c++, winapi, screenshot, desktop

[This document on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image) is quite famous, it's used everywhere, including some answers on StackOverflow. But, this gives me an image that is around 7MB in size.

How do I reduce its size?

Using the <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> button, then pasting it to MSPaint and saving it, gives me an image that is around 224KB in size, which is a lot smaller.

Comment: It's a BMP -- and probably on a high-density screen. BMP images are not compressed which results in large file sizes. You need to use a lossy format like JPG or a lossless format like PNG, both use compression to make the image file size smaller. There are lots of image libraries you can use that will do this for you.

Comment: [Save an image as jpg.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-setting-jpeg-compression-level-use)

Comment: Windows comes with JPEG and PNG encoders as part of the [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-about-windows-imaging-codec). Either one can be used to compress image data.